# Deleting first index in list until it's empty

Tags: java, list

firstPlayer and secondPlayer alternate on getting score from the first index of the list.

firstPlayer gets index 0, then removes that value. if the value is an even number, the remaining list gets reverse.

Then, secondPlayer does the same thing. But somehow getting an error on this part.

Every time each player gets a value, it's concatenating.

In the end, the difference of first and second player is calculated.

This is what I get:
[image]

```
import java.util.*;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        list.add(4);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(3);
        
        int firstScore = 0;
        int secondScore = 0;
        
        int i = 0;
        
        int firstPlayer = 0;
        int secondPlayer = 0;
        
        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println(list);
            firstScore = list.get(i);
            list.remove(i);

            System.out.println(firstScore);
            
            if (firstScore % 2 == 0) {
                Collections.reverse(list);
            }
            
            firstPlayer = firstScore + firstPlayer;
            
            System.out.println(list);
            secondScore = list.get(i);    //this line gets an error but if there's no while loop, it works fine  
            list.remove(i);

            System.out.println(secondScore);
            
            if (secondScore % 2 == 0) {
                Collections.reverse(list);
            }
            
            secondPlayer = secondScore + secondPlayer;
        }
        
        System.out.println(firstPlayer - secondPlayer);
    }
}
```

Comment: And do you have a question?

Comment: You are checking if the list is empty, but you are not breaking the loop when it becomes empty. This means that you are trying to access the first element of an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem ist, that your list is only 5 numbers long and you do the empty check only before the first Players turn.

In the last run of the while loop, the first player gets the last number and without a check, the second player asks for his number, but now the list is empty...

To fix this, you have to put a empty check before the second player gets his number:

```
System.out.println(list);
if (list.isEmpty()) {
    break; // if the list is now empty break the loop
}
secondScore = list.get(i); // if the list was empty we can now be sure that the code interpret won't reach this here
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution,

```
import java.util.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    list.add(4);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(3);
    /*
    list.add(6);
    
    if there are even no. of list items present then the loop get 
    finished before getting error, because having even values and each loop deletes 2 value is proportional.
    
    */
    
    int firstScore = 0;
    int secondScore = 0;
    
    int i = 0;
    
    int firstPlayer = 0;
    int secondPlayer = 0;
    
    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(list);
        firstScore = list.get(i);
        list.remove(i);

        System.out.println(firstScore);
        
        if (firstScore % 2 == 0) {
            Collections.reverse(list);
        }
        
        firstPlayer = firstScore + firstPlayer;
        
        if(!list.isEmpty()) {   //your code gets error because, try to access value in an empty list.
            System.out.println(list);
            secondScore = list.get(i);
            list.remove(i);

            System.out.println(secondScore);
            
            if (secondScore % 2 == 0) {
                Collections.reverse(list);
            }
            
            secondPlayer = secondScore + secondPlayer;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println(firstPlayer - secondPlayer);
}
```

From above code, the if condition added for second player is need to be checked because if the list contains odd number of values then the last element deleted by the first player then second cannot access any value.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

In Java 21 and up you can easily do this using the methods inherited from `SequencedCollection`:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(4);
list.add(2);
list.add(1);
list.add(4);
list.add(3);

int firstScore = 0;
int secondScore = 0;

int firstPlayer = 0;
int secondPlayer = 0;

while (!list.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(list);
    firstScore = list.removeFirst();

    System.out.println(firstScore);

    if (firstScore % 2 == 0) {
        list = list.reversed();
    }

    firstPlayer = firstScore + firstPlayer;

    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(list);
        secondScore = list.removeFirst();

        System.out.println(secondScore);

        if (secondScore % 2 == 0) {
            list = list.reversed();
        }

        secondPlayer = secondScore + secondPlayer;
    }
}

System.out.println(firstPlayer - secondPlayer);
```

Note that I had to include the second empty check inside the loop, as observed by several others.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually best to process only one element of a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) in a loop. In the [`while`] loop in your code, you are processing two elements – which is the cause of your problem as explained in the other answers.

In the below code, the [`while`] loop processes a single element and uses a "flag", i.e. a boolean variable, to determine whose turn it is.

Note that the below code requires minimum Java 21 as it uses [sequenced collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) which were first added in JDK 21.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Players2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(4, 2, 1, 4, 3));
        int score1 = 0;
        int score2 = 0;
        System.out.println("list: " + list);
        System.out.println("score1 = " + score1);
        System.out.println("score2 = " + score2);
        boolean player1 = true;
        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            int score = list.removeFirst();
            if (player1) {
                player1 = false;
                score1 += score;
            }
            else {
                player1 = true;
                score2 += score;
            }
            if (score % 2 == 0) {
                Collections.reverse(list);
            }
            System.out.println("list: " + list);
            System.out.println("score1 = " + score1);
            System.out.println("score2 = " + score2);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output when I run the above code:

```
list: [4, 2, 1, 4, 3]
score1 = 0
score2 = 0
list: [3, 4, 1, 2]
score1 = 4
score2 = 0
list: [4, 1, 2]
score1 = 4
score2 = 3
list: [2, 1]
score1 = 8
score2 = 3
list: [1]
score1 = 8
score2 = 5
list: []
score1 = 9
score2 = 5
```